# Android Studio Mac Gradle Issues

Tags: java, android, gradle

I've been trying to get Android Studio to sync my apps Gradle for forever. It works on my VM and on my old Thinkpad but not my native Mac. I feel like I've tried everything. I keep getting this error message:

Event Log:
1:13 PM Gradle sync failed: path must be canonical but got: '/Users/a../.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.6-all/bcst21l2brirad8k2ben1letg/gradle-4.6/lib/gradle-logging-4.6.jar!' (1 m 33 s 326 ms)

Actual log line:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path must be canonical but got: '/Users/a../Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar!' 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path must be canonical but got: '/Users/a../Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar!'

No matter the version of Android Studio or Mac OS. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

May be not use a gradle wrapper but instead download a gradle distribution and test it.